# Read infile with Unix pipe and sort it

Tags: c, unix, pipeline

I have an exercise where I should read an infile text and pass them with Unix pipes (fork() etc) and print them to the screen for starters.I ' ve accomplished that but now I need to sort the characters from the infile within the pipe (exec sort) and then print it out .

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

FILE *readchar = fopen("text1", "r");
    char ch;
    int fd[2];
    int i = 0;
    char readbuffer[1024];
    int ret = pipe(fd);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }

if (fork() == 0)
{
printf("childprocess\n");

 while(1)
{     
ch = fgetc(readchar);
if(ch==EOF){
   break;
}
write(fd[1],&ch,1); 
dup2(1,fd[1]);
execlp("sort", "sort",  (char*) NULL); //this is crashing 
printf("%c",ch);
}


printf("\n");
exit(0);
printf("end of childprocess\n");
}else
  {
  wait(0);
  printf("%d: parentprocess\n", (int)getpid());
  read(fd[0],readbuffer,sizeof(readbuffer));

  printf("that was in the pipe : \n");
  printf ("%s",readbuffer);
  printf("\n");      


  }

    return 0;
}
```

Can I use the execlp sort in the while(1) loop ? What I mean is everytime a character goes into the pipe ,exec sorts the pipe .
Or maybe I can sort the entire pipe after the while(1) statement (after all characters are added in the pipe)? The code now just crashes in the first loop when execlp sort starts .

The infile Data:

```
abcdefg
123456
XXXXXX
01010101
```

Comment: this line: `write(fd[1], buf, sizeof(buf));` is writing possible garbage after the actual input.  Suggest: `write(fd[1], buf, strlen(buf));`

Comment: when calling `fork()` the code needs to keep the returned value in a `pid_t` variable,   Then the code needs to check for all three possible returned conditions, not just check for 0 else assume the parent is executing.

Comment: before the child calls `exit(0);` it should call: `close(fd[1]);`  assuming that the OS will cleanup such left open file descriptors is a bad programming practice

Comment: the code cannot assume that the child transmitted a terminating NUL char ('\0') so the parent should keep the returned value from the call to `read() and use that count to place a NUL char into the input buffer.

Comment: once the parent, after a call to `fork()` closes the `fd[1]`, it is closed forever, so the next loop's child will not be able to write to the pipe because the `fd[1]` because it is already closed

Comment: this first call: `pid = fork()` should be removed

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1024  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` or `#define` statement to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `pipe()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Which the code does on the second call to `pipe()`  However, that overlays the two file descriptors from the first call to `pipe()`.   Strongly suggest removing the first call to pipe()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `pipe()` twice; delete the first.  You call `fork()` twice; it isn't clear cut which one you should delete.  However, deleting the first means the fewest other changes.  You also need to avoid closing `fd[1]` in the parent so that the second and subsequent children still have a valid pipe to use.

#### Slightly flawed code

This code at least works when the output is sent direct to the terminal (not via a pipe):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *readchar = fopen("infile", "r");
    char buf[1024];
    int fd[2];
    int i = 0;

    int ret = pipe(fd);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), readchar) != NULL)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("child proceess\n");
            close(fd[0]);
            write(fd[1], buf, sizeof(buf));
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(0);
            printf("parent proceess");
            //close(fd[1]);
            read(fd[0], buf, 1024);
            printf("buf: %s\n", buf);
            printf("%d\n", ++i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With a copy of the source copied to `infile`, it produced the correct number of lines of output (double spaced).

The code is still not good for many reasons, not least of which are that 'one process per line' is somewhat wasteful, and 'fork a process with the content of the line in a buffer, then write that buffer back to the parent (which already knew what was in the buffer) is a bit pointless'.  OTOH, it does use a pipe to communicate between two processes.

---

#### More work needed, but no infinite loop

When I run the code shown on the data file:

```
abcdefg
123456
XXXXXX
01010101
```

the output I get is:

```
child proceess
parent proceessbuf: abcdefg

1
child proceess
parent proceessbuf: abcdefg

1
parent proceessbuf: 123456

2
child proceess
parent proceessbuf: abcdefg

1
parent proceessbuf: 123456

2
parent proceessbuf: XXXXXX

3
child proceess
parent proceessbuf: abcdefg

1
parent proceessbuf: 123456

2
parent proceessbuf: XXXXXX

3
parent proceessbuf: 01010101

4
```

Hmmm...that's a bit odd: first 1; then 1, 2; then 1, 2, 3; then 1, 2, 3, 4.  (I didn't spot this in my trial with the last 43 lines whizzing past double spaced.) Let me investigate.  But there's no infinite loop, so you merged something incorrectly from my code into yours.

---

#### Piping output changes line buffering to full buffering

I used the name `xc19` for the program (source `xc19.c`).

The problem with the code above is that I used `xc19 | pbcopy` to run and copy the output to the clipboard (on a Mac).  That meant that the output was no longer line buffered but rather 'fully buffered'.  So, the intermediate outputs were still in the standard I/O buffer of each child, so when the child process exited, that information was flushed.  But each child got more information in the buffer.

The fix is very simple: use `fflush(0);` or `fflush(stdout);` in the parent code.  Here's a version with more compressed output (and diagnostics in the form of PIDs being printed):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *readchar = fopen("infile", "r");
    char buf[1024];
    int fd[2];
    int i = 0;

    int ret = pipe(fd);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), readchar) != NULL)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("%d: child proceess\n", (int)getpid());
            close(fd[0]);
            write(fd[1], buf, sizeof(buf));
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(0);
            printf("%d: parent proceess\n", (int)getpid());
            read(fd[0], buf, 1024);
            printf("%d buf: %s", ++i, buf);
            fflush(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
58878: child proceess
58876: parent proceess
1 buf: abcdefg
58879: child proceess
58876: parent proceess
2 buf: 123456
58880: child proceess
58876: parent proceess
3 buf: XXXXXX
58881: child proceess
58876: parent proceess
4 buf: 01010101
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , but unfortunately even with this changes the code still refuses to work . My infile has 4 lines with 6 and 7 characters in each line and when I try to run it goes to an infinite loop . I stopped the program when it the "i" was close to 26.000 .

Comment: Then you (a) should have shown the data in the question and (b) didn't copy the changes carefully enough.

Comment: I've updated my answer (twice).  The problem in the first code was slightly careless coding and testing (the output on the test data I used — the program source code — was so verbose I didn't spot the repetition).  I'm confident that the revised code is now correct enough.  It should still be upgraded to check reads and writes, etc.  But it does work to my satisfaction.